# Cannot connect remotely to SQL Server 2014 using SSMS under one condition

Tags: sql-server, networking, tcp, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two servers on two different subnets, namely server A and server B.
Both of them use a non-standard TCP port for connection (i.e. 1438).

I can connect using SSMS from server B to server A without a problem, but when changing the direction (from server A to server B), I am often met with two errors "Access is denied" and "The remote server refused the connection".

Below are some notes about the case:

1. I have changed the default client TCP/IP connection port from 1433 to 1438 in the Configuration Manager of server A
2. If I created an alias and defined to connect using server B port 1438, the connection is successful
3. When I connect, if I specify tcp:Server B,1438 then the connection is successful as well
4. telnet to server B 1438 is successful
5. Already allow connection in the Windows firewall of server B
6. Only when I try to connect with the server name "Server B", it will load for a while and prompt me the error
7. The reason I need to connect using only "Server B" but not "tcp: Server B, 1438" or "Server B Alias" is because I am trying to setup replication. When setting up server B as subscriber I need to connect from server A to server B, and for some reason the only thing SSMS allow me to use is the server name of server B, which is "Server B".

I then tried the following and it seemed to have setup the replication successfully for now:
I remote desktop to server B, using the SSMS there, I connect to server A. From the remoted server A, I setup the replication there and for some reason, now the connection to server B works (perhaps it used the established connection to connect back?).

However, if I remote desktop to server A, and try the connection again from there, I am still met with the error.

Would like to see if anyone had this problem as well and grateful if someone could shed some light on this, thank you.

Comment: plz post entire errors

Comment: it is very generic: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5)
Access is denied

Answer (score 0):

If you think all setup is ok then Please try this

Restart SQL Server Service from local services On Server B.

I always stuck in this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried restarting the SQL Server Service on both servers, no luck still :(